# Add a hover effect to all elements of a class

Tags: html, css

I made a simple website, it looks like this:
[image]

But, as you can see, the hover effect only works on where the mouse actually is! (here ipsum) But my aim is that the hover works on all elements! So i added a class with the hover effect p.hov:hover, but see it yourself:

```
<span id="motha">
  <blockquote>
  <p class="hov">Lorem</p> 
  <p class="hov" >ipsum</p>
  <p class="hov" >dolor</p> 
  <p class="hov" >sit</p>
  <p class="hov" >amen</p>
  </blockquote>
  </span>

 p {    
color:#f2f2f2;
background:#ff4a4a;
font-size: 75px;
line-height: 74px;
font-weight:700;
margin: 0 5px 24px;
float:left;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 5px 24px;
font-family: 'Route', serif;
   }

  p.hov:hover {box-shadow: 
 1px 1px #666,
 2px 2px #666,
 3px 3px #666;}
```

Sorry for my english! And Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the placeholder text ends in "amet".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want all blocks to have a shadow, put the hover on the parent element:

```
blockquote:hover p.hov {
    box-shadow: 
    1px 1px #666,
    2px 2px #666,
    3px 3px #666;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead use `<p>` tag for each one why wont use them all?
Here an example:

HTML

```
<span id="motha">
   <blockquote>
      <p class="hov">Lorem</p>
      <p class="hov" >ipsum</p>
      <p class="hov" >dolor</p>
      <p class="hov" >sit</p>
      <p class="hov" >amen</p>
   </blockquote>
</span>
```

CSS

```
blockquote:hover p.hov {
    box-shadow: 
    1px 1px #666,
    2px 2px #666,
    3px 3px #666;
}
```

Comment: you'll lose the whitespace then.

Comment: You can allways add &nbsp;..

Comment: i mean the whitespace between the red blocks.

Comment: Oh you right let me edit, vote me up :)

Comment: yes, but your css isn't right yet. As it will show a shadow under the blockquote (and thus on the whitespace too).

Comment: Sharp eye my friend :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
blockquote:hover p.hov
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N8QeW/)**

Comment: modified version so that the hover effect is still on inbetween words: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N8QeW/5/)

Answer (score 2):

```
#motha:hover p{
    box-shadow: 
       1px 1px #666,
       2px 2px #666,
       3px 3px #666;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think it will work for you

```
.hov:hover{
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px  #666; /*For Mozilla*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px  #666; /*For Chrome & safari*/
    box-shadow:         3px 3px  #666; /*For other*/   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving styles on hover of parent elements to  all the child elements.

```
#motha:hover p{
    box-shadow: 
     1px 1px #666,
     2px 2px #666,
     3px 3px #666;
}
```

if you only wanna target the elements having the class `.hov` u can use this css also

```
#motha:hover .hov{
    box-shadow: 
     1px 1px #666,
     2px 2px #666,
     3px 3px #666;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

**HTML**

```
  <span id="motha">
  <blockquote>
  <p class="hov">Lorem</p> 
  <p class="hov" >ipsum</p>
  <p class="hov" >dolor</p> 
  <p class="hov" >sit</p>
  <p class="hov" >amen</p>
  </blockquote>
  </span>
```

**CSS**

```
p {    
color:#f2f2f2;
background:#ff4a4a;
font-size: 75px;
line-height: 74px;
font-weight:700;
margin: 0 5px 24px;
float:left;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0 5px 24px;
font-family: 'Route', serif;
   }

.highlight {box-shadow: 
 1px 1px #666,
 2px 2px #666,
 3px 3px #666;}
```

**Script (include jQuery):**

```
$(".hov").mouseover(function(){
    $(".hov").addClass("highlight");
});

$(".hov").mouseout(function(){
    $(".hov").removeClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: You are right. just saw your answer. much better